# Entity framework - assignment to list behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Recently I spoted strange behavior in EntityFramework 6, given following program
can anyone explain to me why

```
parent.Children = new List<ChildObject> { new ChildObject("newChild", "newValue") };
```

actually *adds* new child to list of Children instead of removing old children and adding new ones.

Using `db.Parents.Include(x => x.Children).First()` to load parent solves problem, which makes this behavior even stranger...

Was this conscious design choice or is it actually a bug?

Full test program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EF_PlayWithList
{
    public class ChildObject
    {
        public int Id { get; protected set; }

        public int ParentId { get; protected set; }
        public string Name { get; protected set; }
        public string Value { get; protected set; }

        protected ChildObject() { }

        public ChildObject(string name, string value)
        {
            this.Name = name ?? "";
            this.Value = value ?? "";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}: {1}", this.Name, this.Value);
        }
    }

    public class ParentObject
    {
        public int Id { get; protected set; }
        public string Name { get; protected set; }

        public virtual IList<ChildObject> Children { get; set; }

        protected ParentObject() { }

        public ParentObject(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Children = new List<ChildObject>();
        }

        public void AddChild(ChildObject child)
        {
            this.Children.Add(child);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Parent '{0}' with {1} childs.", this.Name, this.Children.Count);
        }
    }

    class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ParentObject> Parents { get; set; }

        public TestDbContext()
            : base()
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ParentObject>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Children)
                .WithRequired()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();

            modelBuilder.Entity<ParentObject>()
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ParentObject>()
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ChildObject>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.ParentId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ChildObject>()
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestDbContext>());

                using (var db = new TestDbContext())
                {
                    var parent = new ParentObject("superFooParent");
                    parent.AddChild(new ChildObject("foo", "1"));
                    parent.AddChild(new ChildObject("bar", "2"));

                    db.Parents.Add(parent);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                using (var db = new TestDbContext())
                {
                    var parent = db.Parents.First();

                    parent.Children = new List<ChildObject>
                    {
                        new ChildObject("newChild", "newValue")
                    };

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                using (var db = new TestDbContext())
                {
                    foreach (var parent in db.Parents.Include(x => x.Children))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(parent);

                        foreach (var child in parent.Children)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", child);
                        }
                    }
                }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to ask the EF design team if this was intentional, and if so, why they made that decision.  We can only guess.

Comment: As above, it would be a guess, but I don't think it's a bad thing that you have to explicitly remove all `Children`. Furthermore, you would open up all sorts of possible referential integrity problems if you allowed this sort of replacement.

Comment: You suggest you spot a difference compared to some previous version. Or are you just asking why EF behaves like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call SaveChanges on your DbContext, the framework inspects all entities *that it knows about* to see what's been modified, added, removed, etc...  If the old list of children was never loaded then the DbContext doesn't know about them, and they will not be removed.  That is the intended behavior.  If you want the framework to make database changes for you then you must allow the DbContext to load the affected entities; otherwise you'll need to use pure SQL.